# Which browsers support Object.observe?

Tags: javascript, browser, observable, object.observe

Which browsers, if any, support `Object.observe`? I'm surprised I'm unable to find any info on this.

(And are you aware about any estimated times of arrival for this feature?)

About Object.observe: *"Object.observe allows for the direct observation of changes to ECMAScript objects. It allows an observer to receive a time-ordered sequence of change records which describe the set of changes which took place to the set of observed objects."* — see [ecmascript.org](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:observe#solution), the Solution section.)

---

**Edit** November 2015: Apparently Object.observe has been cancelled:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/object-observe-withdrawn

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe
*"I plan to withdraw the Object.observe proposal from TC39"*

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/save-object-observe-please-make-weakmap-weakset-observable
*"Save Object.observe()! (please)"*

Comment: I think it'll be a while before you see this broadly supported in the wild. It's not even in the [latest draft specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)... *Edit*: Ah, and that's because they're targeting ES7. So yeah, not for a *while*.

Comment: There is a [shim](https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No browsers. If its not true today, [it will be true someday](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/an-update-on-object-observe), and then this can be the accepted answer.

Comment: 7 years later and I still wake up from time to time wishing for `Object.observable`.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [kangax's Browser Compatibility Table for `Object.observe`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/#Object.observe)

It is part of ECMA Script 7 Specifications, it seems. Luckily, at the time of this writing, my current browser, Chrome 33, is the only one which supports it :)

If you like to enable it in Chrome 33,

1. Visit `chrome://flags/`
2. And enable `Enable Experimental JavaScript`

Comment: Interesting. So many things show up in Firefox first, rather than Chrome. This must be one spearheaded by the V8 members of the committee...

Comment: Note the original link doesn't go the the right place anymore. Use http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/

Comment: The table by kangax shows it also only being available in Chrome 33-37 with the "Experimental Javascript features" flag. I have Chrome 38 and it's working without that flag enabled, so (assuming Kangax's table is correct) it was enabled by in Chrome 38.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's due to angular.

Comment: Any ideas when we will see it in FF?

Comment: @Nikos I could only find [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=800355) and unfortunately no one is working on it as of now :'(

Answer (score 8):

**[Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org)** is a new and promising framework that intends to implement *Web Components*, for which `Object.observe()` is an integral part.

It provides polyfill implementation for "evergreen" browsers; the latest ones available.
Moreover, **[they track what browser have native support for this feature](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html),** so it speeds up their implementation.

[This polyfill is available as a separate library on GitHub.](https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js)

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js - it is not a polyfill, rather a separate library which may use `Object.observe` if it is implemented in current browser

Comment: @Victor to clarify; it provides a polyfill to observe changes to objects. The library will indeed fall back to (slow) dirty checking, instead of native `Object.observe`.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 35+ supports Object.observe() Method.

More details here: [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/)

Update: It's moved to chrome 36 beta.

Comment: just got Chrome 35 but it doesn't seem to be available...even after enabling experimental js in the flags...weird?!

Comment: yep it's not in 35 but in 36 https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/469145484901511168 a bit of confusion around

Comment: It now seems that its in chrome 36 beta. Need to checkout though.

Comment: http://www.chromestatus.com/features/6147094632988672 - marked as "Enabled by default" in Chrome 36

Comment: Works by default on Chrome 36 (currently beta)

Answer (score 2):

It used to be present in both Chrome & Opera, but the feature has been removed from both browsers after [**the standards committee withdrew the proposal for this feature**](https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/11/object-observe-withdrawn)!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 36+, Opera 30+. My favorite way of answering these questions is http://caniuse.com. It's clear, consice, and has instant search.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [object-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-observer) library.

basarat's answer is definitelly the right one - nowadays no browser supports it.

Most of the polyfills performing 'dirty-checks' - not the best way to achieve observance IMHO.

Better way is to pick up one of the several libraries providing the same functionality utilizing native Proxy capabilities, [object-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-observer) being just one of them.